# There are no non-constant morphisms from $\mathbb{A}^1$ to a cubic curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, curves, morphism

Consider the cubic curve $X$ defined, over an arbitrary field $K$, by the equation $y^2 =x(x−1)(x−\lambda)$
in $\mathbb{A}^2$, where $\lambda \neq 0,1$. Show that there are no non-constant morphisms $f : \mathbb{A}^1 \mapsto X$.

My attempt:

Suppose $f: \mathbb{A}^1 \mapsto X$ is such that $f(t)=(h(t),g(t))$ for some $g(t),h(t) \in K[t]$ non constant. Then $g^2=h(h-1)(h-\lambda)$ and if $(t-\alpha)$ is a factor of $g(t)$ we have $(t-\alpha)^2$ divides the product $h(h-1)(h-\lambda)$; however $h,h-1$ and $h-\lambda$ are pairwise relatively prime, hence they don't share an irreducible factor $(t-\alpha)^2$. It follows that $(t-\alpha)^2$ divides one of $h$,$h-1$ and $h-\lambda$. Moreover, if $(t-\beta)$ divides one of $h$,$h-1$ and $h-\lambda$ then it divides $g^2$ and hence $(t-\beta)^2$ must divide one of $h$,$h-1$ and $h-\lambda$. It follows that each of $h(t)$,$h(t)-1$ and $h(t)-\lambda$ is a square in $K[t]$, but this is impossible unless $h$ is constant (and consequently, also $g$ is).

The problem is that a morphism is defined by quotient of polynomials, or is it enough in this proof to use polynomials?

Comment: It is enough to use the polynomials since these are affine varieties. See Corollary 3.8 Chapter 1 Algebraic Geometry - R.Hartshorne.

Comment: @random123 this corollary? "The functor $X \mapsto A(X)$ induces an arrow-reversing equivalence of categories between the category of affine varieties over $K$ and the category of finitely generated integral domains over $K$."

Comment: Yes. That is correct.

Comment: @random123 and how can I use it?

Comment: The question was is it enough to use polynomials to define morphisms. The corollary says that morphisms between affine varieties are determined by the induced map on coordinate rings. The coordinate ring of affine line is $k[t]$ and the coordinate ring of the curve is $k[x,y]/(y^2-x(x-1)(x-\lambda))$. A map from latter to former are defined by sending the variables $x,y$ to polymials in $k[t]$ satisfying the relation $(y^2-x(x-1)(x-\lambda))$.